# Grappling an Air/Water/Fire Elemental

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, grapple

Consider the [air elemental](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-air/small-air-elemental). It is made from air, or clouds, or smoke, or something like it. Any attempt to grab hold of such materials with your bare hands would fail, realistically speaking. Thus, barring the use of some very specific magic, one might presume that it is impossible to grapple an air elemental. Similar arguments would hold for [fire](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-fire/small-fire-elemental) and [water](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-water/small-water-elemental/) elementals, for both fire and water cannot be gripped.

In D&D 5e, this is handled simply and directly by granting air, fire and water elementals immunity to the grappled condition.

In Pathfinder, however, I can find nothing indicating that these creatures are immune to being grappled. They usually have a solid bonus to Escape Artist checks, representing their slippery nature, but RAW anyone can grapple an air elemental as easily as a solid creature.

I note that the Pathfinder rules for [grappling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) give both the grappler and the grapplee the grappled condition, so straight-up immunity to the [grappled](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled) condition would complicate matters if the elemental were to attempt to grapple another creature (which is something these elementals could reasonably do). But hypothetically they could have been granted an ability similar to the [*freedom of movement*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/freedom-of-movement) spell, yet they were not.

Am I missing something? Is being able to grapple an air elemental a correct reading of Pathfinder's rules? Obviously, the DM has the freedom to rule as they deem fit, but if they decide to follow RAW how would one rationalise grappling something made of air?

Comment: @ShadowKras I've adjusted some of the phrasing based on your feedback. Rather than asking _does it make sense_ I now ask _is this intended_, which is slightly more objective and a lot less personal.

Comment: On the contrary, [design intent questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/8610) are a bugbear, too. It sounds like the question wants a reasonable explanation for these rules, and I don't think there is a *reasonable* explanation—one that makes sense based on, for instance, real-life scientific principles—for how one can grapple an air, fire, or water elemental. You may want to pose this question [on a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610) where folks can discuss it, spitball, and offer straight-up unsupported but interesting opinions.

Comment: (That's not me picking on your question nor my downvote! I think this is a fine question to have, and one that I've wondered about myself. I just don't think the site's equipped to handle it!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan, noted. I am indeed asking for a reasonable explanation of the rule. This, I concede, is probably too opinion based, although blurry's answer has done a good job addressing the issue with a comparison to other creatures in Pathfinder.

Comment: I could remove the line on designer intent if that makes any improvement, however marginal. In principle, I could shift the question to 'what would happen if I made it impossible to grapple air elementals?', but that's probably a sufficiently different question to justify writing a new question.

Comment: I don't see how this is opinion based... Sure, it's asked because of an opinion, but it's asking for rules to substantiate or disprove that opinion.

Comment: If you look up the giant squid, they can grapple foes without gaining the grappled condition.

Comment: @Ifusaso the wording, now, is much better than what it had before. I am removing my close vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Grappling Elementals works as Normal

[Fire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-fire/huge-fire-elemental/), [Water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-water/huge-water-elemental/), and [Air](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-air/huge-air-elemental/) Elementals (as a creature type) in Pathfinder have no rules that prevent grapple. Additionally, Elementals don't have rules that prevent grappling either.

To show that this is where you'd expect to see such a rule; note that [Swarms](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Elemental) have the following rule:

> **Swarms** are never staggered or reduced to a dying state by damage. Also, they **cannot be** tripped, **grappled**, or bull rushed, and they cannot grapple an opponent.

I'd point out that the three linked (CR 7) huge elementals have CMD 34; which is pretty good for their CR (nearly 10 higher than many other CR 7 monsters) making them rather difficult to grapple relative to the other creatures in their CR rating. This seems to hold for the elementals of other size; but I haven't performed an exhaustive check.

## Conceptualizing it

Let's start by mentioning they're already solid enough to hit you with melee attacks, trip you, be stabbed by swords and shot by arrows; so if those don't bother you, you can probably stop reading.

I think given the above; if the DM doesn't want you to grapple and doesn't make Elementals Incorporeal I'd find it odd. I'd note that Oozes can often be grappled too; so simply slipping out of your grasp as you grapple them seems inconsistent. I honestly can't see this coming up.

Comment: I just wanna point out, you can grapple any liquid or gas IRL with a tight enough bag. Presumably it involves pushing a fluid with your body enough that its center of mass can't escape.